# Android Studio Preview asking for Java 1.8 when I already have it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I try to preview my app inside of the preview function that comes with android studio.

[image: My Error]

My Java version is: "1.8.0_91"

My computer is a mac book air. It seems the problem, among my classmates, seems to be only affecting mac users. If you would like me to provide anymore info please ask.

I have installed  the required JDK from the oracle website.
My classmates reinstalled java on their computers but the error shown in the image still persists.

[image: I am using a proper jdk]

My Jdk is hooked up correctly I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your JDK location set correctly in your android studio settings.

File > Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK location

[image]

Comment: I am using the correct JDK and the editor is hooked up to the correct location

Answer (score 0):

Was it worked before ? I think your JDK location Path is not set properly. It should be till the JDK folder as

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

not to its subsequent folder.

Comment: I am using a mac, I don't have a c drive

Comment: Plus, I made sure that it was connected to the JDK as you can see in the image at the bottom of my question.